# How to filter results based on order in Solr?

Tags: sorting, solr, filtering, facet

I need to facet inside n documents which are selected like

```
... ORDER BY something DESC LIMIT 100
```

Is that possible with Solr? How?

Comment: you mean facet within a single page of results?

Comment: Well, yes, kind of, but with sorted results. Example to get stats from top 10 values

Comment: try asking/suggesting it on http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK no, that's not supported / implemented. Facets aren't really meant to be "stats" but a guidance to the end-user. Picture yourself browsing a faceted interface and seeing facets change whenever you change sort order or paging. Faceted browsing would be useless if it worked like that.

I think this would be a nice feature for the [StatsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) though.

Comment: Yup, I agree, that would be nice feature, along with percentile calculation.

Answer (score 1):

this is a total hack, but here goes...

1. do your initial query, and get your results back.
2. construct a new query, like so:

http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=id%3A123+OR+id%3A456...(keep OR-ing them up)...&facet=true&facet.field=something

where you concatenate all of your ids to a new query using OR. then, when you facet on your field, the facet summary will only apply to the results.

Comment: Well, yes, but this ain't that good solution for example to get top 10000 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible with results grouping (now in trunk!):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

... the only problem is that you can set only one 'facet.field' (i.e. group.field)

But the great thing is that you get scored facets!