# SOLR - How to have facet counts restricted to rows returned in resultset

Tags: search, facet, solr

`/select/?q=*:*&rows=100&facet=on&facet.field=category`

I have around 100 000 documents indexed. But I return only 100 documents using rows=100. The facet counts returned for category, however return the counts for all documents indexed.

Can we somehow restrict the facets to the result set returned? i.e 100 rows only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter results based on order in Solr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997783/how-to-filter-results-based-on-order-in-solr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but i don't think it is possible. The facets are always based on all the documents matching the query.

Comment: I think this is the answer to my query, and it is indeed very unfortunate that this feature has not yet been implemented in SOLR. The hacks spelt out in the other question linked above are also not really worthy, on a production server with huge data. Would appreciate if the SOLR creators can implement this feature in the near future

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is possible in any direct manner, as was pointed out by Pascal.

I can see two ways to achieve this:

1. Method I: do the counting yourself visiting the 100 results returned. This is very easy and fast if they are categorical fields, but harder if they are text fields that need to be tokenized, etc.
2. Method II: do two passes:

   1. Do a normal query without facets (you only need to request doc ids at this point)
   2. Collect all the IDs of the documents returned
   3. Do a second query for all fields and facets, adding a filter to restrict result to those IDs collected in setp 2. Something like: 

      `select/?q=:&facet=on&facet.field=category&fq=id:(312
      OR 28 OR 1231 ...)`

The first is way more efficient and I would recommend for non-textual filds. The second is computationally expensive but has the advantage of working for all types od fields.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but maybe better than nothing: the results grouping feature (check out from trunk!):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

where facet.field=category is then similar to group.field=category and you will get only as much groups ('facet hits') as you specified!

Answer (score 0):

If you always execute the same query `(q=*:*)`, maybe you can use facet.limit, for example:

```
select/?q=*:*&rows=100&facet=on&facet.field=category&facet.limit=100
```

Tell us if the order that solr uses is the same in the facet as in the query *:*.

Comment: To answer your question first - yes, the order is the same in the facet as in the query.
However, here we cant use facet.limit as facet.limit only limits the number of facets to return. It does not limit the resultset.

So,
select/?q=*:*&rows=100&facet=on&facet.field=category&facet.limit=100

will only return 100 category values. It will not limit the resultset to 100, as is the requirement here.

Comment: down voted as facet.limit only restricts the number of facets returned, not the rows acted upon, as the above comment points out